# Sticky BottomPlaceholder

Tags: sharepoint-framework, footer, applicationcustomizers

Is there anyway to make a bottomPlaceholder footer (using ApplicationCustomizer) sticky? The footer I am making is rather large and cannot be on the screen all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A class that derives from the ApplicationBaseCustomizer class
2. Use of the this.context.placeholderProvider.tryCreateContent()
   method to get a reference to the appropriate placeholder and it’s
   content - and the fact that it gives you the DOM element to
   manipulate (e.g. set innerHTML)

You could refer below code:

```
import { override } from '@microsoft/decorators';
import { Log } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  BaseApplicationCustomizer, PlaceholderContent, PlaceholderName, PlaceholderProvider
} from '@microsoft/sp-application-base';

import * as strings from 'Cob12ApplicationCustomizerStrings';
import styles from './AppCustomizer.module.scss';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';

const LOG_SOURCE: string = 'COBApplicationCustomizer';
const FOOTER_TEXT: string = "This is the bottom zone";

// used if you wish to pass properties to your extension..
export interface ICob12ApplicationCustomizerProperties {
  TopContent: string;
}

export default class Cob12ApplicationCustomizer
  extends BaseApplicationCustomizer<ICob12ApplicationCustomizerProperties> {

  @override
  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    console.log("onInit: Entered");

    console.log("Available placeholders: ",
      this.context.placeholderProvider.placeholderNames.join(", "));


    // bottom placeholder..
    let bottomPlaceholder: PlaceholderContent = this.context.placeholderProvider.tryCreateContent(PlaceholderName.Bottom);
    if (bottomPlaceholder) {
      bottomPlaceholder.domElement.innerHTML = `<div class="${styles.app}">
                  <div class="ms-bgColor-themeDark ms-fontColor-white ${styles.footer}">
                    <i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Info" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; ${escape(FOOTER_TEXT)}
                  </div>
                </div>`;
    }

    return Promise.resolve<void>();
  }
}
```

And the CSS is implemented by adding an SCSS file in your extension’s directory - named AppCustomizer.module.scss(in this code) and has the following content:

```
.app {
  .footer {
    height:60px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:2.5;
    font-weight:bold;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: darkgreen;
  }
}
```

Remember this is imported to the class for your customizer e.g:

```
import styles from './AppCustomizer.module.scss';
```

[Reference](https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2017/06/SPFx-Application-Customizer-Global-JS-Page-Header.html)

**Update**:
Try below CSS:

```
    .footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This is what I've already got basically, however I need it to only show up on the bottom of the page (when its scrolled all the way down) and not always in the view port. This may not be possible

Comment: Try updated CSS, you could modify the colors based on your requirement.

Comment: I can't tell if that worked yet, SharePoint's layout is a bit weird for testing this, but I'm going to assume that it did, so thank you :)

Comment: @Styrac Please upvote and mark the answer as accepted since it helped you

Comment: This doesn't work if you need the bottom not to be fixed, which is like that by design